# How I can get the body from a HTTP response?

Tags: http, tcp, arduino, esp8266

Hey I am doing and Arduino project, and I want to get the body from an HTTP request, here is the code:

```cpp
// This will send the request to the server
client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
             "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
             "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
delay(100);
int liniea_info = 0;
while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    if(liniea_info == 13){Serial.print(line);}
    Serial.print(liniea_info);
    ++liniea_info;
}
```

This works good, without the integer `liniea_info` returns me this:

```
Requesting URL: /output/***.csv?colors=11
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 17 Jun 2017 08:09:31 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
Cache-control: private

34
colors,day,timestamp
11,12,2017-06-17T07:48:10.619Z

0
```

I thought that with the `int liniea_info` I will get only the line that I want that is the line `"11,12,2017-06-17T07:48:10.619Z"`, but no, with this only prints the first line.

Anyone sees what I am doing wrong or how to do it?

Comment: That's not C, please remove the tag or replace it with the correct one....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use HTTPClient library. This library handles request and response.

Add to includes:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
```

And simply:

```
HTTPClient http;
http.begin("http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv");
int statusCode = http.GET();
Serial.println(http.getString());
http.end();
```